# How to convert excel to pdf with orientation to horizontal using Python

Tags: python, excel, pdf, orientation, win32com

I have an `excel sheet` which I want to convert to pdf using `python`. I am able to do this using below code:

```
import win32com.client
from pywintypes import com_error

WB_PATH = 'test.xls'
PATH_TO_PDF = 'test.pdf'

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

excel.Visible = False

try:
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(WB_PATH)
    ws_index_list = [1]
    wb.WorkSheets(ws_index_list).Select()
    wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, PATH_TO_PDF)
except com_error as e:
    print('failed.')
else:
    print('Succeeded.')
finally:
    wb.Close()
    excel.Quit()
```

This is working fine but the problem is its converting the excel to pdf in vertical layout. I have many columns in excel due to which some of the columns goes into 2nd page which doesn't look good. Below is the snapshot:

[image]

Above is the excel sheet screenshot.

[image]

Above image is the 1st page of the pdf which contains data till Roll Stop Time column and rest it contains in 2nd page:

[image]

How can I change the orientation to horizontal so that all the columns fits on the first page. Please help. Thanks

Updated code:

```
import win32com.client
from pywintypes import com_error


WB_PATH = 'test.xls'

PATH_TO_PDF = 'test.pdf'

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = False

try:
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(WB_PATH)
    wb.Worksheets("sheet")

    ws_index_list = [1]
    ws_source = wb.WorkSheets(ws_index_list)
    ws_source.PageSetup.Orientation = 2
    ws_source.Select()

    wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, PATH_TO_PDF)
except com_error as e:
    print('failed.')
else:
    print('Succeeded.')
finally:
    wb.Close()
    excel.Quit()
```

But above code is giving error:

```
AttributeError: <unknown>.PageSetup
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import win32com.client
from pywintypes import com_error

WB_PATH = 'test.xls'
PATH_TO_PDF = 'test.pdf'

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

excel.Visible = False

try:
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(WB_PATH)
    ws_source.PageSetup.Orientation = 2 # orient the format before you print to pdf
    ws_index_list = [1]
    wb.WorkSheets(ws_index_list).Select()
    wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, PATH_TO_PDF)
except com_error as e:
    print('failed.')
else:
    print('Succeeded.')
finally:
    wb.Close()
    excel.Quit()
# I'm not a very experienced programmer but this should help. I would orient
# the file first before printing it to pdf
```

Comment: what is `ws_source`?

Comment: I have updated the code but its giving error, can you check